# How to break out of an inner nested Parallel.Foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, nested-loops, parallel.foreach, .net-4.8

Why doesn't this break statement work? My goal is to break out of the *inner loop only*, but keep processing the outer loop. It is hitting the `Console.WriteLine()` no matter what I do.

I have tried:

1. `innerLoopState.Break()`
2. `innerLoopState.Stop()`

Neither stop the loop before the `Console.WriteLine()`...

```
private static ParallelOptions ParallelCityOptions => new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};

private static ParallelOptions ParallelPeopleOptions => new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
}

[Test]
public void NestedParallelForeach()
{
    var listOfCities = new List<string> {"Atlanta", "Denver", "Scranton",};
    var listOfPeople = new List<string>() {"Bob", "Sally", "Craig", "Bill"};

    Parallel.ForEach(listOfCities, ParallelCityOptions, city =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(listOfPeople, ParallelPeopleOptions, (person, innerLoopState) =>
        {

            if (person == "Bill")
            {
                // do something
                innerLoopState.Break();
                Console.WriteLine("Should never hit this line.");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is: curry the outer loop state and break it as you wish:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfCities, ParallelCityOptions, (city, outerLoopState) =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfPeople, ParallelPeopleOptions, (person, innerLoopState) =>
    {

        if (person == "Bill")
        {
            // do something
            outerLoopState.Break();
            innerLoopState.Break();
            Console.WriteLine("Should never hit this line.");
        }
    });
});
```

However all of the elements in your array will be processed by your code at once, since there's so few compared to the number of cores a modern computer has. Simply requesting a parallel loop break won't magically break all threads, it will just stop new ones from being processed.

Comment: This will break out of the outer loop too? I was hoping to keep looping through the cities, but just break out of the specific city if "Bill". I have a real world situation for this, just simplified it for brevity sake.

Comment: Your question asks how to break out of *nested* loops, am I misreading it?

Comment: I have rephrased the question to more clearly represent my goal. Sorry about that. I meant to ask how to break out of the inner loop only, but keep processing the outer loop

Comment: Then you already wrote the correct code. If you're asking why execution goes beyond the `Break`, it's because as I said `Break` flags that no new items should be processed and nothing more. If you want to not hit the next line, simply delete it. Or add a `return;` before it, if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: That's exactly what I was having a problem with. I need it to not execute the code after the `innerLoopState.Break()`. Sounds like I just need to add a `return` as well. If you rephrase your answer, I can accept it to give you rep. Thank you for your help!